# Send Grid Email is creating a new thread after an inbound email reply

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm using send grid to send and receive emails. Currently I'm facing an issue that is: It is creating a new email thread after every inbound reply on the existing thread. It is not preserving all the subsequent messages in the same thread. Any Idea? Anyone have access to send grid updated documentations ?

Please find my code below:

```
sgMail.setApiKey(apiKey);
    const msg = {
        to: lead.email,
        from: config.email,
        subject: subject,
        html: body,
        attachments: attachments
    };
    console.log('sendGrid', msg);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        sgMail
            .send(msg)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Email sent');
                resolve('Email sent');
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log('error sendGrid', error.response.body);
                reject(error);
            });
    });
```

Comment: Please post an example of the code you are using to help debugging.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it is creating a new email thread? How are you tracking email threads in your application? As David said, can you share some code?

Comment: My code sgMail.setApiKey(apiKey);
    const msg = {
        to: lead.email,
        from: config.email,
        subject: subject,
        html: body,
        attachments: attachments
    };
    console.log('sendGrid', msg);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        sgMail
            .send(msg)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Email sent');
                resolve('Email sent');
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log('error sendGrid', error.response.body);
                reject(error);
            });
    });